# C# Convert string to array

Tags: c#, arrays, umbraco, umbraco7

So I'm working with umbraco and using the tag datatype. I'm trying to take all tags added to a given node and putting them into an array of strings but when I grab the value it always seems to come out like this:

"[\"Tag1\",\"Tag2\"]"

How can I convert this string of an array back into a regular array? All I have gotten so far was a string of individual characters

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: How do you get this string? Do you use the TagService? Any chance you call `.ToString()` where you should not do it?

Comment: Even the object when I called it like this content.GetPropertyValue<object>("tags") provided a string, probably because I had it saving as json. Trying to get all this with angular and I think I wound up mixing a bit too much together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array format you have provided as an example looks like part of the JSON object.

You could use [JSON.net library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) to parse array token of the JSON object.

```
var array = JArray.Parse(tagString).Values<string>();
```

A complete example is available [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7C4vpI).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you.  I tried doing those replace character answers but i was worried about unusual characters being placed in.  ironically the first tag i am working with is already using an unusual character, a single quote

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
string[] newArray = item.Replace("\"", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',');
```

This would output as `Tag1`, `Tag2` etc...

[image: Example]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then you'll just have `["Tag1"` and `"Tag2"]`, won't you?

Comment: Sure, and it's a start towards the solution. Would you reckon it would've been better as a comment if it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: Absolutely. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var tagString = "[\"Tag1\",\"Tag2\",\"Tag3\",\"Tag4\"]";
var tags = tagString.Trim().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',');
```